# Abrir link em outro navegador no HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicação-web, link

Bom dia pessoal !

Seguinte, eu possuo um código em HTML bem simples, onde tenho uma imagem linkada a um link de uma aplicação local na empresa (a aplicação é web) ou seja quando eu clico na imagem a pagina automaticamente me redireciona a pagina da aplicação web, porém, esta aplicação só pode ser aberta no chrome, e alguns usuários da empresa possuem o explorer como navegador padrão, é possível eu fazer com que este link linkado a imagem faça com que abra uma pagina no chrome ?

Segue abaixo a linha do código atual (onde tem XX.XXX.X.X é o IP da aplicação web):

```html
<article class="thumb">
<a href="http://XX.XXX.X.X/GEOQ" ><target=”_blank”><class="image"><img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" height="150" width="225" /></a>
<h2>GEOQ</h2>
<p>Sistema de não conformidades.</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por segurança não é mais possível um navegador acessar outras aplicações dentro do seu sistema operacional. A menos que o objetivo seja obter algum arquivo ou acessar dispositivos de leitura, o navegador não pode executar programas.

Você pode deixar um aviso na página quanto a qual navegador pode acessar a aplicação, mas o certo seria possível tentar investigar por que uma aplicação só roda no Google Chrome.

Comment: entendi, é pq o programador q vendeu o software fez ela masterizada pro chrome e com dependencias nele ( tambem nao achei correto mas fazer o q a diretoria manda a gente obedece ) pensei em deixar um aviso tambem mas nossos usuarios sao muito amadores e nao sao atenciosos, ainda assim vao ignorar a mensagem abrir no navegador errado e abrir chamado com a TI reclamando do nao funcionamento, por isso pensei na abertura de uma aplicação externa por dentro do code da Intranet

Comment: @RafaelXavierSuarez você pode fazer uma verificação em javascript e quando o site não for acessado pelo google chrome, redireciona pra uma página estática qualquer falando da obrigatoriedade do uso no google chrome